# Getting an error retrieving data from MySQL using Ajax and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to get data from mysql using ajax but it doesn't work. When I run the following code

Here is script of ajax

```js
  $( document ).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "page/tester.php",
            dataType: "html",
            data:null,
            cache:false, //same get error
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert("test");
            },
            error:function()
            {
                alert("sux");
            }
        });});
```

Here script of php file

```
<?
    //$account=$_GET["query"];
    $account="name";
    $password="pass";
    $pass=hash("whirlpool",$password);
    $qy=mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `Username`='{$account}' AND `Password`='{$pass}'"));
    if(mysql_num_rows($qy)==1)
    {
        $result=json_encode(mysql_fetch_assoc($qy));
    }
    echo "queryResults('" . $result . "');";
?>
```

The results of php file if I just open it:

```
queryResults('{"ID":"1","Nickname":"Dorin Yanke","Username":"mineralo","Password":"70b993a77bd5c5c3d9313a746079f5b6149231bfabf4a790556cb7daeafeca091e4bcc930aad28a6791492594b30e212661c09b0e9ef482593781ceda1415f70","Admin":"5","Online":"0","Toolbar_Color":"default","Profile_Pic":"default.png"}');
```

now works fine, now left how to intigrat all these stuff in a array to be able manage all info like "data['ID']"

Comment: Doesn't work is not much of an error description. Please provide some more information on how it behaves.

Comment: Do you have any browser console error messages? What happens when you go to `page/tester.php` in your browser?

Comment: Your response looks like an attempt at JSONP.

Comment: You have `dataType: "json",`, but `echo "queryResults('" . $result . "');";` will result in invalid `json` data. [`"json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object. The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown.`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: In your ajax call add `cache: false`.

Comment: if I run it, the console return alert("sux") instead "test"

Comment: Your title contradicts what you just said. If you're getting the message from the error function then there's probably an error in the PHP that's being called by the Ajax.  So its not just a caching issue like your title says.

Comment: Either remove `dataType: "json"`, change it to `dataType: "html"`, or just do `echo $result ;` in your php. Your `echo "queryResults('" ` is causing a parse error in js.

Comment: thanks, you're right, needed instead json to write html

Answer (score -2):

Mysql_query is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0. Also, I don't see where you would connect to your database. Before you even get to trying to handle an ajax query, can your page show some confirmation of being able to connect to and query a database?

Comment: its connects from one php file where its included

Answer (score -2):

Appand a random number to the end of the url.

url: "page/tester.php?random_number="+Math.random()

Note: Setting cache to false will only work correctly with HEAD and GET requests.
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Also please note that as of jquery 1.8:

Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Please read the documentation before down-voting.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but with Jquery you can just put `cache: false` inside your `$.ajax()`.

Comment: Note: Setting cache to false will only work correctly with HEAD and GET requests.

Comment: Ok, but it also says "The parameter is not needed for other types of requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL that has already been requested by a GET."

Comment: The `success` and `error` settings are not deprecated. Only using the `success` method on the jqXHR object is deprecated. So `$.ajax().success(function () {})` is deprecated, not `$.ajax({ success: function () {} })`. Please read the documentation before posting ;P